# How can I create a JavaScript Variable with my php Variable in a While loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop, echo

I am making a web with information from a MySQL database and I want pictures to appear after clicking a buttom.

```
              echo "<img align=\"left\"src=\"".$path[$y]."\" alt=\"error\">";
              echo "<img align=\"right\"src=\"".$path_edit[$y]."\" alt=\"error\" id=\"$id[$y]\" style=\"visibility:hidden\">";

              echo "_____________________________________";
              echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                echo "function showImage() {
                  document.getElementById(\"$id[$y]\").style.visibility=\"visible\";
                }";
              echo "</script>";
              echo "<br><br>";
              echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"showImage();\" value=\"Show Picture\"/>";
              echo "<p>";
```

I want the second image(The one with $PATH_edit[$y]) to appear after clicking in its buttom. (The buttom appears after each couple of images).
I have all with echo because It's all in the loop and I want it all to display as many times as number of entrances  the database has.
I know I can not use the php variables in Javascript, I tried everything but I can't fix it. I am new with php, html and I have no idea ofJavaScript.

[This is how it looks like without clicking the buttom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZrpX.png)
I know I can put an id to the image but that will only work for the first one.
[This is how it looks like after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wxok.png)
I have also tried this:

```
echo "function showImage() {
                      var id_id =  \"$id[$y]\";
                      document.getElementById(id_id).style.visibility=\"visible\";
}";
```

This is the whole code:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!--- basic page needs
================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Base de Datos ATLAS</title>
<meta name="Una gran base de datos de microscopía" content="">
<meta name="Pablo Cruz" content="">

<!-- mobile specific metas
================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- CSS
================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- script (I tried to put the function here, bu tit does not work either)
================================================== -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- favicons
================================================== -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
```

```
<!-- preloader
================================================== -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="loader" class="dots-fade">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- header
================================================== -->
<header class="s-header header">

    <div class="header__logo">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html">

            <img src="images/logo_sin.png" alt="Homepage" >
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end header__logo -->



    </div>  <!-- end header__search -->

    <a class="header__toggle-menu" href="#0" title="Menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
    <nav class="header__nav-wrap">

        <h2 class="header__nav-heading h6">Navigate to</h2>

        <ul class="header__nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html" title="">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#0" title="">Base de Datos</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="base_de_datos.html">Microscopía Electrónica</a></li>
                    <li><a href="base_de_datos.html">Microscopía Óptica</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#0" title="">Almacén</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="s_mitocondrias.html">Mitocondrias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_nucleo.html">Núcleo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_lisosoma.html">Lisosomas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_vesiculas.html">Vesículas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_golgi.html">Aparato de Golgi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_microtubulos.html">Microtubulos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="s_rer.html">Retículo Endosplamático Rugoso</a></li>
                <!--
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="single-video.html">Video Post</a></li>
                    <li><a href="single-audio.html">Audio Post</a></li>
                    <li><a href="single-standard.html">Standard Post</a></li>
                </ul>
            -->
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.usal.es/" target="_blank"title="">USAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html" title="">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>   <!-- end header__nav -->

        <a href="#0" title="Close Menu" class="header__overlay-close close-mobile-menu">Close</a>

    </nav> <!-- end header__nav-wrap -->

</header> <!-- s-header -->


<!-- s-content
================================================== -->
<section class="s-content s-content--top-padding s-content--narrow">

    <article class="row entry format-standard">


        <div class="entry__header col-full">
            <h1 class="entry__header-title display-1">
                Galeria de Mitocondrias.
            </h1>
        </div>


        <?PHP
        require "connect.php";
        $x=0;
        $y=0;
        $autosuma = 222;
        $database = "tfg";
        $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);
        if ($db_found) {
          $SQL = "SELECT * FROM id_organulo WHERE mitocondria = 1";
          $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);

          while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $id[$x] = $db_field['id'];
            $comentario[$x] = $db_field['comentario'];
            $nombre_de_foto[$x] = $db_field['nombre_de_foto'];
            $autor[$x] = $db_field['autor'];
            $path[$x] = $db_field['PATH'];
            $path_edit[$x] = $db_field['PATH_edit'];
            $ruta_perfil_foto[$x] = $db_field['ruta_perfil_foto'];
            $x = $x+1;
            echo "<div class=\"col-full entry__main\">";
                echo "<div class=\"entry__author\">";
                  echo "<img src=\"".$ruta_perfil_foto[$y]."\"alt=\"\">";
                  echo "<div class=\"entry__author-about\">";
                    echo "<h5 class=\"entry__author-name\">";
                      echo "<span>$autor[$y]</span>";
                      echo "<a href=\"0\">$nombre_de_foto[$y]</a>";
                    echo "</h5>";
                  echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<br>";
            echo "</div>"; // <!-- s-entry__main -->
            echo "<center>";
            echo "<img align=\"left\"src=\"".$path[$y]."\" alt=\"error\">";
            echo "<img align=\"right\"src=\"".$path_edit[$y]."\" alt=\"error\" id=\"$id[$y]\" style=\"visibility:hidden\">";
            echo "_____________________________________";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo '<input type="button" onclick="showImage('.$id[$y].');" value="Show Picture"/>';
            echo "<p>";
                print $comentario[$y];
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</center>";
            $y++;
          }
        }
        else {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        }
        mysqli_close($db_handle);
        ?>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
          function showImage() {
            var id = <?php echo (json_encode($id[$y])); ?>;
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
        }
        </script>";





          <div class="row pagination-wrap">
            <div class="col-full">
                <nav class="pgn" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="pgn__prev" href="s_mitocondrias_result_3.php">Prev</a></li>
                        <li><a class="pgn__num" href="s_mitocondrias_result_1.php">1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="pgn__num" href="s_mitocondrias_result_2.php">2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="pgn__num" href="s_mitocondrias_result_3.php">3</a></li>
                        <li><span class="pgn__num current">4</span></li>

                        >
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <hr>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p> <h5>Codigo de rotulación:</h5>  </p>
          M: Mitocondrias <br>
          dM: Doble membrana <br>
          cM: Cresta Mitocondrial <br>
          R: Ribosomas <br>
          N: Nucleo <br>
          eu: Eucromatina <br>
          Nu: Nucleolo <br>
          Mtu: Microtúbulos <br>
          Ec: Esterocilio <br>
          </p>

        </center>
        <?php $y++; ?>















    </article> <!-- end entry/article -->
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the exact problem? What **exactly** have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: I have this in my website, I am trying to make for each while time the image and the buttom appear, The buttom doesn't work. In the web console there's this error ReferenceError: showImage is not defined.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Checking the generated source code to see where `showImage` was defined and how should not be too hard

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I am not an informatic or something close. I just watched a couple of videos and I am trying to make the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first a little advice, separate php, javascript and html. Together it is difficult to read and maintain. Otherwise you create a function at each pass of the loop. It doesn't bother me that nothing works like that. Try it like this:

Send the id of your image as a parameter to the function. **A single function, which will be after the loop**.

```
function showImage(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
}
```

and at each passage of the loop send to the function the id of the image like this :

```
<input type="button" onclick="showImage(\"$id[$y]\");" value="Show Picture">
```

Finally it will give something like that :

```
<?php
    while(...){
       echo '<img align="left" src="'.$path[$y].'" alt="error">';
       echo '<img align="right" src="'.$path_edit[$y].'" alt="error" id="'.$id[$y].'" style="visibility:hidden">';
       echo '_____________________________________';
       echo '<br><br>';
       echo '<input type="button" onclick="showImage('.$id[$y].');" value="Show Picture">';
       echo '<p>';
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage(id) {
       document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
    }
</script>
```

Use **'** for echo and not **"** when displaying html, it's more practical.
Good luck for the future

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried but I got an error in the website: ReferenceError: showImage is not defined

Comment: And I am not sure of the meanign of the # in getElementById("#"+id). Shall I put something there?

Comment: I edited the question so as to put the code as I have it right now

Comment: you're right about getElementById("#"+id) it's just getElementById(id).

Comment: But I still got this error in the web console : ReferenceError: showImage is not defined. Shall I put the function in other place?

Comment: Look in the tree structure of your html, if the functions are there and that they all have the identifier well informed. Like : <input type="button" onclick="showImage(25);" value="Show Picture">
It's work for me !

Comment: As an extra side note, Using litterals is also recommended when writing HTML with PHP vars in them. I don't know if it's faster, but it codes way easier.

Comment: Hi, I hope you have solved your problem. If so, can you mark the answer as good, otherwise show us all the code to help you better.

Comment: It doesn't work yet, the error still appears. I will edit the post so as to put the whole code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put the javascript function as I wrote it to you (without escaping the slashes). Remove the line "var id = <? Php ...", you don't need it. because the function retrieves the id as a parameter when clicking!
In addition $id[$y] is no longer of interest because you are outside the loop!

Comment: With pleasure. give a like :)